# Custom reply to Adress not working properly in Pardot?

Tags: send-email, pardot, reply-mail-management

In the custom reply to adress, we can set up the email adress that will receive the reply of the recipient ( if he/she send a reply )

But When we test, we always get a reply in the sender email address not the reply to adress

I don't have an idea on how to fix this, but I readed a comment & could not understand what the recipient can do to reply to the correct answer.

What pardot says is this :

[image]

Which is quite cleat, but if we do a simple test :

[image]

It is like I did not set up a reply to address ?

Is there something that the recipient must have some setup in the mailserver used ?

I checked the article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320469&type=1) & could not understand what it means exactly ?

*it is ultimately up to the recipients’ mail server to decide if that specification is honored. This is due to the set up of the recipients’ inbound mail-server. They can be set up to send out-of-office notifications to the Reply To address, or the From address.*

Does that mean that Gmail & outlook mail severs ( Outgoing & Incoming ) are one of those mail servers that won't send a reply to the custom reply to adress set up in Pardot ? ( I tested both )..

Additional Question : If Yes, then why this feature if it is not going to work for the most used mail severs ?

Comment: Mail servers may have configuration that ignores, removes or rewrites Reply-To. That would not be generic config, it'd be something that a particular organization (users o of this mail server) decided to implement. [Mail clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696850/is-the-reply-to-header-universally-supported-among-email-clients) are another layer that impacts the behavior of Reply-To. In the recipient's mailbox, if you see that the Reply-To header is correct, then the issue is with mail client. If the header is not set or diff from what you have in Pardot, it might be their server.

Comment: ...and last but not least, it can be a Pardot-side issue. You'd have to examine the email message when it leaves Pardot to see if it contains the right headers. It might be best to open a support case with Salesforce and ask for assistance.

Comment: @identigral "If the header is not set or diff from what you have in Pardot, it might be their server.", I don't see the reply-to in the header in GMAIL, does that mean it is something from our side ? because, I am checking other emails from other organizations ( udemy for example ) & and I see the the reply-to in the header ? forgive me but I am new to such problems, I may not understand some of the tech words

Comment: If you don't see the header, the issue is either on Pardot side (header was not added to outbound message) or recipient's mail server (header was removed/etc)

Comment: How can I check If the header is added to outbound message then ?

Comment: You mean it is Pardot in the backend that does not those headers I guess..

Comment: Yes. If your Pardot config appears to be correct, then it might be an issue with Pardot engine. You should open a support case to investigate.

Comment: Thanks <3, those infos were useful